# Start with Couchbase N1QL query in xampp

Tags: php, couchbase, sql++

I was trying to query data from Couchbase server using PHP and N1QL. Please see the code below.

```
<?php
$cluster = new CouchbaseCluster('127.0.0.1:8091');
$bucket = $cluster->openBucket('travel-sample');

 $q = CouchbaseN1qlQuery::fromString("SELECT * FROM `travel-sample`")->consistency(CouchbaseN1qlQuery::REQUEST_PLUS);
    $res = $bucket->query($q);

    var_dump($res);
?>
```

Unfortunately, this return NULL. I am usinf Couchbase server 3.0 and PHP SDK. Cam someone help me to correct my N1QL query ?

Regards,
Tismon Varghese

Comment: Just to clarify, you say you're using couchbase server 3 but you seem to query the travel-sample, which was introduced in cb 4 beta IIRC... Also I assume you downloaded n1ql dp4 as a separate service for querying?

Comment: Hi @SimonBaslé, You are right; i'm using Couchbase server 3.0, and the bucket 'travel-sample' is the one i created manually for testing. Thanks for your hint (installing N1QL dp), i will try to install this for Couchbase 3.0 and run again.

Comment: You're best off installing Couchbase 4.0 Beta (at couchbase.com/download) instead of the older standalone N1QL DP.  Couchbase 4.0 Beta has an updated N1QL which is well integrated to the rest of the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, i was using Couchbase 3.0, so i'm suppose to use N1QL DP3. So i downloaded DP3 from the below URL

`https://s3.amazonaws.com/query-dp3/couchbase-query_dev_preview3_x86_win.zip`

Extract it, put it on the directory where Couchbase installed (This is not necessary i guess). Extracted directory contains two directories; data and static in addition to a start_turotial.bat and some other files.

Since the .bat file is connected to data directory, we have to change this to get data from Couchbase server. For that, do the following.

1. Take a backup of the .bat file; right click on it and select 'edit'
2. change the line `cbq-engine -couchbase dir:data`  to `cbq-engine -couchbase http://127.0.0.1:8091/` and save it
3. Double click on the bat file so that a console window will be popped up (This should be open as long as the query runs). I addition to this, a webpage also opens automatically in your browser; if not, follow the instruction on the popped console window.

..and you are good to go!!!

Regards,
Tismon Varghese.